# Link subheadings as bookmarks in Microsoft Loop

Tags: loops

Im editing a page in MS Loop. I wish to link to one of the subsections in the same page (just like how a contents page does).

eg:
I want to link the subheading named "Setup" in the Introduction paragraph, so that readers will quickly navigate to that subheading situated in the same page quickly, without reading other content.